# Ansible Run Command

Tags: ansible

Fairly new to Ansible.

I have a text file which contains a list of ec2 instance ip addresses. Secondly, I have a .yml file which applies tags to an array of ec2 ips.

Does anyone what run command I would use to pass the list of ips stored as a text file? I did it once a while back before. I forgot the run command, and cannot find it in my history.

Answer (score 0):

`I have a text file which contains a list of ec2 instance ip addresses`: you probably mean an `inventory` file.

to include it in your ansible command execution, add `-i <file name>`

example:

```
ansible-playbook -i <inventory file> <yml file>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#group-variables) with your IP's, for example, something like `/tmp/my-ec2-vms`:

```
[my-ec2-vms]
10.1.2.10
10.1.2.11
10.1.2.12
10.1.2.13
...

[my-ec2-vms:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python
```

Then for testing, you could use the [ping module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ping_module.html), for example:

```
ansible -i /tmp/my-ec2-vms -m ping all
```

If that works later you could just run your playbooks:

```
ansible-playbook -i /tmp/my-ec2-vms my-playbook.yml
```